# SyncReply URL different after upgrading from ServiceStack 3.9 to 4.x

Tags: c#, servicestack

I've got some legacy ServiceStack clients using this call:

```
        public ProductUpdateResponse GetProductUpdate(string productId, string currentVersion, string licenseId, string machineCode)
    {
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseAPI);
        var resp = client.Send<ProductUpdateResponse>(new ProductUpdate() { ProductId = productId, ProductVersion = currentVersion, LicenseId = licenseId, MachineCode = machineCode });

        return resp;
    }
```

If I run this pointed to a serviceStack 3.9 server, it works.  If you run it pointed at a 4.x server I get a "Not Found" error.

I've traced this down to the SyncReply path being different.

The client POST's to

```
/api/json/syncreply/productupdate
```

But on the 4.x server, that same syncreply path is different

```
/api/json/reply/productupdate (works)
/api/json/syncreply/productupdate (Not Found Error)
```

The DTO's are exactly the same on the clients and the servers.

Is there some config setting I need to change in the 4.x ServiceStack to keep things backward compatible?

Comment: I just found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534493/servicestack-syncreply-removed-not-backwards-compatible which tells how to change the clients so that they can talk to a 4.x server, but I don't want to have to update XX clients, that doesn't fix the backward compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by adding the legacy syncreply route to the request DTO on the server.

> [Route("/json/**syncreply**/productupdate", Verbs="POST")]

```
//Request DTO
[Route("/products/{ProductId}/updates/{ProductVersion}")]
[Route("/products/{ProductId}/updates")]
[Route("/json/syncreply/productupdate", Verbs="POST")]
public class ProductUpdate
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductVersion { get; set; }
    public string MachineCode { get; set; }
    public string LicenseId { get; set; }
}
```

Seems like the PredefinedRoutesFeature, which is where the default handler paths are defined, should have an option to maintain legacy fallback routes....

Answer (score 0):

The legacy [pre-defined routes were renamed in the v4 refactor](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2014/release-notes.md#the-big-refactor-of-v4), the Routing docs shows the format of [v4's pre-defined routes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#pre-defined-routes).

ServiceStack v4 doesn't accept v3 routes, but the latest version of v3 accepts both v3 and v4-only routes and allows the Service Clients to be configured to use the renamed routes with:

```
client.UseNewPredefinedRoutes = true;
```